# regular expression to capture content of a group and reuse them

Tags: c#, regex, mysqli

How can I write a regular expression to replace

```
VALUES ('some text')
```

with

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'some text') AS tmp...
```

Basically, I have an input file, with multiple *Insert* statements. I want to use Regex to convert each insert statement into a *IF NOT EXISTS then INSERT* Statement (and run in in MySQL).

So, this is my input:

```
 INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele) VALUES ('Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022')
```

and this is the desired output:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT VersionNumber FROM ReleaseInfo WHERE VersionNumber = '1.0.0.1'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
VALUES\s*\(([^()]*)\)
```

And replace this with

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT $1) AS tmp
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2gclXF/2/).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
VALUES   # match VALUES
\s*\(    # whitespaces, optionally, (
([^()]*) # capture anything inside ()
\s*      # another whitespaces, optionally
\)       # )
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, what does $1 mean?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini: It is the content of the first captured group, see the updated answer.